# How to reattach a jquery function to a rendered template?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view that is rendering my template - the template consists of many elements that I am making editable inline with a jquery plugin. The elements are made editable with a .editable() call to each div accordingly.

I have a template that includes elements like:

```
<div id="pricing">some value</div>
<div id="terms">some other value</div>
```

Everytime the view is re-rendered, my elements lose the .editable() ability. The plugin applies it's own class names, etc.

In my view's render, I am able to make this work by doing:

```
var MyView = new Backbone.View.extend({ 

    render: function() { 
        var html = this.template(this.model.toJSON());
        this.$el.html(html);
        this.$el.find('#pricing').editable();
        this.$el.find('#terms').editable();    
});
```

Is there a better way to do this without explicitly declaring .editable() to every div i need in the view's render method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there are many ways around it. The call to `editable()` has to be made after the dom elements are ready to be manipulated with the plugin. Since you are replacing the HTML you have to wait until the view is re-rendered. I would suggest giving the divs you need to be editable their own class like `editable`. Then you could use the class selector instead of doing it for each div separately.

```
<div id="pricing" class="editable">some value</div>
<div id="terms"  class="editable">some other value</div>
```

Then you could do :

```
this.$(".editable").editable(); //or this.$el.find('.editable').editable();
//instead of 
this.$el.find('#pricing').editable();
this.$el.find('#terms').editable();  
//etc.
```

This will save you having to write a new call for every div and you won't have to constantly update it as you add/remove divs from your view.

Comment: I think `this.$el.find('.editable').editable()` or `this.$('.editable').editable()` would be more reliable than `$('.editable').editable()` as you don't know when `this.$el` will be in the DOM so you don't know when `$('.editable')` will find everything you care about.

Comment: @muistooshort True. It could also be faster depending on how large the DOM tree is since there is a limited context for the search. I'll update the anwser